# Making a simple real-time graph

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to fetch some data from the database and plot it into a real-time graph. I'm using this as an example: http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/examples/ajax/index.html

THE JSON is like this:

```
  "networks": {
         "eth0": {
             "rx_bytes": 5338,
             "rx_dropped": 0,
             "rx_errors": 0,
             "rx_packets": 36,
             "tx_bytes": 648,
             "tx_dropped": 0,
             "tx_errors": 0,
             "tx_packets": 8
         }
       }
```

But my code doesn't plot anything even tho the `rx_bytes` array has data inside. What am I missing here?

```js
 var rx_bytes = [], tx_bytes = [], cpu = [], mem = [];

    //Options
    var options = {
        lines: {
            show: true
        },
        points: {
            show: true
        },
        xaxis: {
            tickDecimals: 0,
            tickSize: 1
        }
    };

    //Initial Plot
    $.plot("#cpuStats", rx_bytes, options);
    $.plot("#memStats", mem, options);
    $.plot("#networkStats", cpu, options);

    function getStatistics() {
         $.ajax({
            url: '/getStatistics',
            type: 'post',
             dataType: 'json',
            success: function (statistics) {
                console.log(statistics);
                var network = statistics.networks.eth0;
                rx_bytes.push(network.rx_bytes);
                console.log(rx_bytes);

                //Plot
                $.plot("#cpuStats", rx_bytes, options);
                //get data again
                getStatistics();
            }
        });
    }
    
     getStatistics();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/jquery.flot.js"></script>
```

Comment: anyone please??

Comment: There's nothing obviously wrong. To debug, ask yourself, (i) does it work with hard-coded data? (ii) does the server deliver what you expect?

Answer (score 0):

You need a X value for each new data point.  In this case you probably want a timestamp.  Also, don't call getStatistics() inside your success handler.  It may lead to too much recursion.  Instead use [setTimeout()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Talk:DOM/window.setTimeout)

```
success: function (statistics) {
    var network = statistics.networks.eth0;
    var now = new Date().getTime();
    rx_bytes.push([now, network.rx_bytes]);
    $.plot("#cpuStats", rx_bytes, options);
    setTimeout(getStatistics, 1000);
}
```

This updates once per second.

Here's a more robust [jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/vkvmpL6o/1/) that also handles the initial period where data hasn't filled the X axis and also drops old data once that period expires.